# SNS notification scheduling

Tags: parse-platform, amazon-sns, moengage

Is it possible to schedule our push notification through SNS (to send it at a particular time of the day) which we are able to parse or moengage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **CloudWatch Events** to send a message to an Amazon SNS topic on a schedule. (Note: CloudWatch Events is not available in every region.)

CloudWatch Events **can be triggered by**:

- A schedule (eg every hour, or with a cron expression)
- An API call (eg whenever an EC2 instance is launched)
- Auto Scaling (eg an instance is removed)
- An EC2 instance changes state (eg terminates)

CloudWatch Events **can trigger**:

- A message to an Amazon SQS queue
- A message to an Amazon SNS topic
- A message to an Amazon Kinesis stream
- An AWS Lambda function
- The start/stop/termination of an Amazon EC2 instance
- Creation of an Amazon EBS snapshot

See documentation: [Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html)

Comment: The problem is CloudWatch allows now only 100 rules

Answer (score 0):

AWS contain `EventBridge` service that we can use to send a message to an `Amazon SNS` topic on a schedule. `Amazon EventBridge` is a serverless event bus service that makes it easy to connect your applications with data from a variety of sources. According to AWS docs, `Amazon EventBridge` is the preferred way to manage your events. `CloudWatch` Events and `EventBridge` are the same underlying service and API, but `EventBridge` provides more features.

You can configure the following AWS resources as targets for `EventBridge`:

- List item
- Lambda functions
- Amazon EC2 instances
- Streams in Amazon Kinesis Data Streams
- Delivery streams in Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose
- Log groups in Amazon CloudWatch Logs
- Amazon ECS tasks
- Systems Manager Run Command
- Systems Manager Automation
- AWS Batch jobs
- AWS Step Functions state machines
- Pipelines in AWS CodePipeline
- AWS CodeBuild projects
- Amazon Inspector assessment templates
- Amazon SNS topics
- Amazon SQS queues
- Systems Manager OpsItems
- Built-in targets: EC2 CreateSnapshot API call, EC2 RebootInstances API call, EC2 StopInstances API call, and EC2 TerminateInstances API call
- The default event bus of another AWS account
- Amazon API Gateway REST API endpoints
- Amazon Redshift clusters (Data API statement execution)